# Remove shipping row from Woocommerce admin edit order pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

How can I hide/remove shipping row from admin order page? Please help, Thanks in advance.

[image: click to view the screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide shipping lines and details a from admin order single pages you will use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_items', 'custom_order_get_items', 10, 3 );
function custom_order_get_items( $items, $order, $types ) {
    if ( is_admin() && $types == array('shipping') ) {
        $items = array();
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Works well. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at this?
https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-woocommerce-product-shipping-information/

It removes the shipping info from products so maybe also from the whole site.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. but I need to hide the shipping row from the order page not from the product page.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your function file

```
<?php add_action( 'init', 'hide_shipping_details' );
    function hide_shipping_details() { 
        global $pagenow;
        if( is_admin() && $pagenow == "user-edit.php") { ?>
        <style> #fieldset-shipping{ display: none !important } </style>
    <?php } }
```

you can change css as per your requirement

Comment: Can you check the class name of the shipping field

Comment: The class name is 'label'. but it will hide all the items with the same class name. I need to hide shipping row only

Comment: Can you send the screenshot with i wanna check the class name

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
add_action('admin_footer', 'my_custom_script');

function my_custom_script() {
  ?>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery(".wc-order-totals .label:contains('Shipping')").parent().hide();
    });
</script>
<?php
}
```